# bootstrap popover arrow goes away when I add scrollbar to popover window

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I get the arrow when there is no scrollbar but it goes away when I add scroll bar to the popover content.
I couldn't get it running on jsfiddle. So i am posting the code here.

CSS

```
.pop-div .popover {
    max-width: 310px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

HTML

```
<li>
    <div class="pop-div">
        <a href="#" id="myid" rel="popover" >click me</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
$("a[rel=popover]").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: '/myurl',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#myid").popover({
                placement: 'top',
                title:'title',
                html:true,
                content:data
            });
        }
    });
 });
```

Comment: This is really sad :( but if you want help, it would be good to show what you exactly did. http://jsfiddle.net/. Also edit your question because it will get flagged like "Not a real question" Because well you didn't really ask a question.

Comment: Specify your issue and snippet of code ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the arrow is supposed to appear below the popover but since you are telling it to scroll vertically, it can't "get out" of the parent. I suggest you use the `.popover-content` class provided by Bootstrap to enable scrolling on the inner content only

**CSS**

```
.pop-div .popover-content {
    max-width: 310px;
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y:scroll;
}
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kaZK5/1)**

Comment: Yes.. I could see it working on jsfiddle. but unfortunately it's not working on my machine. Is there anything else I need to do ?... also my data is very large.... does that make any difference?

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using? and how is it behaving in your site?

Comment: bootstrap-popover.js v2.3.2 ... it works as expected... i could see the popover arrow if I don't add scrollbar but the text overflows... is there any other way to fix it?

Comment: can you post a fiddle with an example of your markup just as it shows after setting the content of the popover?

Comment: I saw in the above fiddle example that even if remove <div class-'popover-content'> tag ... the arrow is visible.  my fiddle will exactly be the same.. the only difference i have is content. I called ajax request & it's response i m showing in popover.

Comment: You are right, I didn't realize Bootstrap already used the popover-content class, so you don't need to wrap your data, just update your CSS, in your original code change `.pop-div .popover` to `.pop-div .popover-content` and make sure to clear the cache on your browser as it may not be updating when you visit the page

Comment: Bootstarp popover have class "popover-content".So we can write the style directly to the class "popover-content".Please do not forget to menition overflow-x as hidden and overflow-y as scroll or vice-versa because defining only overflow-x or overflow-y will create regressions.

Answer (score 0):

I added overflow:auto to the popover-content and max-width:100% to popover it works well for me

```
.popover .popover-content {
```

overflow: auto;
}